# Servomotor turning only between 30 and 130 degrees

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have an arduino and a servomotor, I have a basic code using Servo.h to turn the servomotor.

this code is :

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo monServo;

void     setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  monServo.attach(13);
  monServo.write(0);
  Serial.print("Angle de 0 degres donne");
}

void    loop()
{

  monServo.write(0);
  Serial.print("angle de 0 degres donne");
  delay(2000);
  for( int iAngle=0; iAngle<= 180; iAngle+=10 )
  { 
    monServo.write(iAngle);
    Serial.println("Wait");
    Serial.print(iAngle);
    delay( 1000 );
  }
 }
```

And the servomotor is working between 30 and 130 degrees.

Does anyone has a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: what happens after 130 degrees or before 30 degrees? Is it that the servomotor doesnt rotate even though the output is shown on the serial debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the brand/ model of the servo, it may require a different range of pulses to get it's full range.  look up the servo and see if you can find the range (should be in microseconds).  you can then attach it with `monServo.attach(13,minpulse,maxpulse)`

you can also do `monServo.write(pulsetime)` and the library will automatically interperate it as a pulse, not degrees since it will be so high.  This is useful for testing the range.

Bon  chance! ;)